# Xamarin Android - Javascript not loading in WebView when using Xamarin.Auth

Tags: javascript, android, authentication, xamarin.android, xamarin.auth

I am having a really strange issue with a single user when using Xamarin.Auth for authentication. This user has a Samsung Galaxy S3. When they try to sign in to their account using Xamarin.Auth, the WebView which Xamarin.Auth uses to display the login page has no JavaScript enabled. This means that they are unable to click the sign-in button on the page, preventing them from signing in.

I can provide code examples, however they do not differ much from the Xamarin.Auth examples/docs. Also, This issue is particular to this user in that I have tested my app with another Galaxy S3 and the authentication works as expected.

I am really unsure as to how to debug this issue, any help would be appreciated.

https://components.xamarin.com/view/xamarin.auth